# C program showing error due to only format specifier

Tags: c

This program showing error due to format specifier I've used here while printing the array address in for loop. If I'm using any format specifier except %p for printing the address like %ld, %u, %d etc, it is showing error that are as follows :

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:18:10: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   printf("Address arr[%d] is %ld\n", i, &arr[i]); 
          ^
```

Here is my code :

```
 // C program to demonstrate that array elements are stored 
// contiguous locations 

#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    // an array of 10 integers. If arr[0] is stored at 
    // address x, then arr[1] is stored at x + sizeof(int) 
    // arr[2] is stored at x + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) 
    // and so on. 
    int arr[5], i; 

    printf("Size of integer in this compiler is %lu\n", sizeof(int)); 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        // The use of '&' before a variable name, yields 
        // address of variable. 
        printf("Address arr[%d] is %ld\n", i, &arr[i]); 

    return 0;
```

I am not able to understand why %p is used here and what can I use to make my program error free

Comment: Why you don't want to use `%p` ?

Comment: I'm not saying I don't want to use but I'm asking is there any other way to print address except %p or not. cause I read some article on google and get to know that %x and %p are same.

Comment: @AshokPandey you should read less such "articles on google". They're wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala okay You means to say we can only use %p here and not anything. Am I right?

Comment: @AshokPandey I've closed this question as a duplicate of another one with gazillion different answers on what you can do instead. But no, the only format specifier for printing a value of a pointer is `%p`, period, and it needs a pointer to void. Any other will print an integer or some other data type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala okay thanks for clarifying my doubt and for your support sir.

Answer (score 0):

A long int is not the same as an address. You should use:

```
printf("Address arr[%d] is %p\n", i, (void *)&arr[i]);
```

Note that using any other specifier than `%p` makes the program (at least) dependent on the architecture. On some architectures the address is 16 bits and on other architectue it is 32 or 64 bits. So for each of these architectures you would need to use a different specifier to handle the different width. `%p` solves this for you.

The standard requires the argument to be a pointer to void (C11, 7.21.6.1), therefore the cast.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down-voted - it was the first answer and it appears to be correct ?

Comment: @PaulR, not sure either. Someone disappointed he/she wasn't the first or so?

Comment: I guess the question is actually "why do I need %p and why do other specifiers produce a warning ?", rather than "how do I fix this warning ?", but the answer is still essentially correct.

Comment: if you are using %p then there's no need of typecasting because program is running successfully. what I want to know that why don't we use %x instead of %p if both are the same.

Comment: @AshokPandey, the fact that the program appears to run successfully does not mean the program is correct. The standard mandates the casting to `void *`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I agreed to your suggestion but how we'll get to know The standard mandates if compiler will not show any error messages. reply as if you are answering a newbie.

Comment: @AshokPandey Use the `-pedantic` flag if you wish to see a compiler diagnostic assuming you are using GCC

Comment: @Spikatrix but I am coding online at GEEKSFORGEEKS platform. is there any possibility to do it what u said.

Comment: @AshokPandey I've checked their online compiler but did not see any way to modify  the compiler flags and options. So I don't think it is possible to do it there.

Comment: @Spikatrix yeah that's why I am not able to do anything there what you said.as I'm learning DS from there

Comment: @AshokPandey I suggest trying out programs locally on your machine. If you insist on online compilers, I'd suggest better ones such as [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc)

Answer (score 0):

The standard provides "%p" for use in printing a pointer address, and it expects the type provided to be `void*`. Your code can be reworked to properly use `"%p"` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (void) 
{ 
    int arr[5], i; 

    printf ("Size of integer in this compiler is %lu\n", sizeof(int)); 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        printf ("Address arr[%d] is %p\n", i, (void*)&arr[i]); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptraddrarr
Size of integer in this compiler is 4
Address arr[0] is 0x7ffe251cac50
Address arr[1] is 0x7ffe251cac54
Address arr[2] is 0x7ffe251cac58
Address arr[3] is 0x7ffe251cac5c
Address arr[4] is 0x7ffe251cac60
```

Not recommended, but you can use a `"0x%lx"` format specifier to obtain the same output, e.g.

```
        printf ("Address arr[%d] is 0x%lx\n", i, (unsigned long)&arr[i]);
```

But, don't, use the proper format specifier provided expressly for this purpose.

Comment: understood sir, and thanks for the new tricks you've share